# SVG image to match font size

Tags: html, image, svg, css

I have a an SVG logo image. I would like to use it like so:

```
<h1>
  <img src="img/logo.svg" onerror="img/logo.png"></img>
  <span>Some header goes here</span>
</h1>
```

How can I ensure that the image always matches line-height of the header text in the `<span>`? Are there better approaches to have a logo in front of the header?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
<img src="img/logo.svg" width="1em" height="1em"/>
```

and make sure your SVG has a suitable viewBox.